# Is there a data type in ANSI standard SQL for holding an arbitrarily large string?

Tags: sql

For my own fun, I'm trying to write an SQL script for building a db that is as cross-RDBMS as possible. It would just create the database, its tables, and maybe populate it with some data.

One table holds coding problems, and I was wondering what data type to use for the description of the problem. If I were using MySQL, I would just use a TEXT type, but I saw that this is not available in (ANSI) standard SQL.

Is there a data type available for arbitrarily large text data that would be standard SQL and compatible with Postgres/MySQL/MSSQL? Or do I just have to use a really huge VARCHAR and hope it's big enough?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have NTEXT. It has TEXT.

Comment: Postgres also has the TEXT datatype.

Comment: Unfortunately, TEXT and NTEXT don't seem to be part of the ANSI standard. I have just updated my question to specify that it should comply with ANSI if possible. Which ANSI depends on what would work better with the largest number of popular RDBMS.

Comment: The ANSI datatype fo that is `CLOB`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard SQL provides the CLOB (character large object) type for holding really large text objects.  However, there are limits on what you can do with such objects, and maybe your DBMS doesn't support the type.  There is also the BLOB (binary large object) type.

Large fields were standardized after the main DBMS already had their own, non-standard facilities, so there isn't as much coherency between the different systems as you'd like.  You would need to define the systems of interest, or accept that whatever you choose will need changing when you move to a different DBMS (or, most likely, both).  There might be a common subset between your systems of interest, but it is relatively unlikely.

Comment: I'm giving this the green check because it answers my answer directly: "Yes, there is--CLOB and BLOB." The other information is useful as well.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you need to decide: what do you want to achieve: ANSI-compatible data types definition or definition compatible with as most DMBS as possible. And those two things are not same. No matter what is written in standards - it's *DBMS* which are maintaining that standards - more or less. So that's why in practical meaning there's little sense in blind following standards, but following specification for certain DBMS is useful.

I'm not saying that standards are all crap and you shouldn't look there. In general, all DBMS are following them - so if your scheme will follow them too - it's a good chance that such scheme will be supported by most count of DBMS, *but that is not guaranteed*.

For example, MySQL has [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) for variable string length (medium length, up to 64Kb) and Postgres has [`TEXT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html) data type too. And so does MSSQL - it also has [`TEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) data type support. So you can use that for all 3 DBMS - but each DBMS has it's own implementation of this data type (for example, in SQL Server it's up to 2Gb size - so, as you can see, too large data that will be successfully handled by MSSQL 2Gb-length TEXT will fail in MySQL). That means - in formal sense, your schema will work in all those 3 DBMS, but in practice there may be problems because each DBMS has different rules for that type.

Comment: `text` in SQL Server is deprecated if I'm not mistaken (in favour of `varchar(max)`). And `text` in MySQL can only hold 64k, for 4GB you need `LONGTEXT`

Comment: Yes, confused `TEXT` and `LONGTEXT`, you're right. Didn't found proof about SQL Server (I mean deprecated `TEXT` data type) - but if I'm wrong, I'll glad to improve my post. I mean proof that keyword `TEXT` itself will be not available

Comment: From the [SQL Server manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187993%28v=sql.90%29.aspx): "*Avoid using these [ntext, text, and image] data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them*"

Comment: Yep, I've noticed (because, obviously, linked that in post) - so that strictly means that keyword itself will be removed too? (and there will be no backward compatibility)?

Comment: I upvoted this since it gave me some useful info on watching out for differing sizes and rules for what is the same named type. My goal is to be ANSI compliant as while making just a few compromises to support a few major DBMS. My priority is Postgres, Oracle, MySQL, and MSSQL in that order. However, that isn't my original question, and I think your info is generally useful for this problem.

Comment: Another DBMS with a TEXT data type is Informix (which also has CLOB; and BYTE and BLOB types too). The client-side data structures used to support TEXT (and BYTE) are arcane and completely different from the types used by any other DBMS (but these are pre-standard implementations). The BLOB and CLOB types are accessed via opaque types and a complex API.